# How to write a txt file in terminal without entering vim

Tags: vim, terminal

i have to write the file right in the terminal, not in vim. Something like this `vim -someflag "text for my file" filename`. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 6):

In bash, just do:

```
$ echo "text for my file" >filename
```

To append, use:

```
$ echo "text for my file" >> filename
```

Comment: Like more the latter as append works like redirect when it is empty or non existent. +1

Comment: Just a small thing to be aware, this is not necessarily exclusively for "Linux".

Comment: @sidyll : I corrected with "bash" (even if many other shells are concerned, but I don't know them)

Comment: Yes, better. Sorry, I didn't want to sound pecky, just to clarify for future readers. We never know. Thank you for adopting my suggestion. Best wishes

Answer (score 1):

Why use vim if you want to write like this?

Use echo instead:

```
echo "text for my file" > filename
```

`man echo` for more information - documentation

Answer (score 1):

'cat' or 'echo' would be the best options for this.

In the absence of an input argument, cat reads from the standard input:

`cat > myfile.txt
[enter your text, then hit ctrl-d]`

Alternatively, echo will write its arguments to a file with redirection:

`echo "text for my file" > myfile.txt`